# How to extract a function given by a content string in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a content of a function given by a string. I'm looking for a way how to convert this string into a function object to call it.

```
content = "def my_function(x):\n    return x**2"
my_function = extract_function_from_string(content) # extract_function_from_string ???
print my_function(5) # prints 25
```

Perhaps, there's a way to convert the string into a python module and extract the function from it

Comment: @AvinashRaj given that a function isn't a literal, how would that help? `ast.parse` is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: that's not a good way. Perhaps, there's a way to convert the string into a python module and extract the function from it

Comment: Well you could save it to a file then `import` that, but why not look into what `ast` can do for you?

Comment: [`compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#compile)

Comment: compile() requires to have a file. Maybe there's another way to do it without the saving code to a file

Comment: Do you trust the creator of the string to not destroy your computer?

Comment: @Fomalhaut No, it doesn't.

Comment: @Fomalhaut " source can either be a string or an AST object", filename can just be `'<string>'` for that matter.

Comment: Ok, then please, type the usage example applying to my question

Comment: @Fomalhaut What have you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: `compile(content, filename='<string>', mode='exec')`

Comment: @Fomalhaut then just `exec(..)` your compiled object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the function name, you can run exec on the string. Eval will not work as it only targets expressions. See [\r\n vs \n in python eval function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204376/r-n-vs-n-in-python-eval-function). If you don't know the function name, but all your function have the same format you can try something like this:

```
def extract_function_from_string(content):
    exec(content)
    start = 4
    end = content.find("(")
    function_name = content[start:end]
    return eval(function_name)
my_function = extract_function_from_string("def my_function(x):\n    return x**2")
print my_function(5)
```

The train has left the safe and sound python station a long time ago, but I guess this is just a curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exec`

```
>>>content = "def my_function(x):\n    return x**2"
>>>exec content
>>>my_function(5)
25
```

For **Python 3.x**

```
>>>exec(content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) statement:

```
>>> content = "def my_function(x):\n    return x**2"
>>> exec content
>>> my_function(5)
25
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that does not leave safe train of python completely.

```
def extract_function_from_string(content, function_index=0):
    import ast
    tree = ast.parse(content, mode='exec')
    function = tree.body[function_index]
    module = ast.Module([function])
    exec(compile(module, filename="<ast>", mode='exec'))
    return locals()[function.name]

content = "def my_function(x):\n    return x**2"
my_function = extract_function_from_string(content) # extract_function_from_string ???
print(my_function(5)) # prints 25
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the eval function to do this. e.g. eval("print('Hello')").

However, do be advised that this can be a security risk, and there is probably a better way of doing it than parsing a string.

Comment: Try `eval("def my_function(x):\n    return x**2")`

Answer (score -3):

a = "lambda x:x**2"

my_func = eval(a)

print my_func(3)

Comment: did you try running it

Comment: A function **is not a literal**

Comment: This will work with `lambda` but fail on named functions like `def f`. You could suggest this as available specifically with lambdas but you should explain how it works in your answer and not just dump code.